# Flexiprovider NoSuchAlgorithmException SHA-1

Tags: java

I want to use the [flexiprovider library](https://www.flexiprovider.de/overview.html) and I am trying to instantiate a simple de.flexiprovider.api.MessageDigest; with the next code

```
MessageDigest digest = Registry.getMessageDigest("SHA-1");
```

But I get Exception in thread "main" de.flexiprovider.api.exceptions.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA-1. Could you help me please? I need instantiate SHA-1 algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the output result of `Registry.getAlgorithms(Registry.MESSAGE_DIGEST)` I suppose that the code above should be

```
MessageDigest digest = Registry.getMessageDigest("SHA1");
```

*Edit:*

Like most JCE libraries, flexiprovider needs to be registered as a security provider in your program once, so you also need a single call to

```
Security.addProvider(new FlexiCoreProvider());
```

once in your application initialization.

Answer (score 0):

It is need first register the algorithm in the following way:

```
Registry.add(Registry.MESSAGE_DIGEST, de.flexiprovider.core.md.SHA1.class, "SHA-1");
```

Comment: Interesting, because I didn't have to, the code in my answer worked directly. Looking at the javadoc for `Registry.add()` it says that this registers the implementation under the given name, so I think you just created an alias, because the returned implementation of `Registry.getMessageDigest("SHA1")` is of type `de.flexiprovider.core.md.SHA1`.

Comment: when I put just Registry.getMessageDigest("SHA1") I get error, no such algorithm,

Comment: Adapting the example at https://www.flexiprovider.de/examples/ExampleDigest.html I silently put the initialization code snippet into my code as well, so I've edited my answer. Sorry ;)